# Why does Android AlertDialog go full screen?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

If I pass an empty array to `setItems`, my `AlertDialog` goes full screen on an emulator running Android 9. However, on my device running Android 5.1, it does not go full screen, which is the behavior I am trying to achieve.

What could be causing the `AlertDialog` to go full screen on the emulator running Android 9, but not on the device running Android 5.1?

This is how I set up my `AlertDialog`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContextActivity);
builder.setTitle(dialogTitel);


builder.setItems(arrayItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {

               ...     
            }
         });


final AlertDialog Block = builder.create();
Block.show();
```

Here it is on the emulator:

[image]

EDIT: This how it looks on my device running Android 5.1.

[image]

Comment: And what do you want to see with empty list?

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: I tried in emulator nexus_5X android 9 working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use below to set width and height as you wish

```
Block.Show().Window.SetLayout(some_width,some_height);
```

Comment: This has no effect: Block.getWindow().setLayout(50,50);

Comment: you have forgot `.show`  . use like this `Block.Show().Window.SetLayout(50,50);`